# Assigning local variables of struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, local-variables

In header there is deffinition of  structure:

```
struct SNeuron
{
    //the number of inputs into the neuron
    int                   m_NumInputs;

    //the weights for each input
    vector<double>  m_vecWeight;


    //ctor
    SNeuron(int NumInputs);
};
```

In cpp file there is:

```
SNeuron::SNeuron(int NumInputs): m_NumInputs(NumInputs+1)

{
    //.. some body
}
```

What actualy the header of constructor of structure does? There is construction

```
 SNeuron::SNeuron(int NumInputs): m_NumInputs(NumInputs+1)
```

Is it the behaviour of this strane construction same like if I write it for example in Java like this:

```
class Neuron {

int m_NumInputs;

    public Neuron(int numInputs) {
      this.m_NumInputs = numInputs+1;


      //... rest of constructor body
    }
}
```

So the expected behaviour is that I take the numInputs (input of structure) and

```
: m_NumInputs(NumInputs+1)
```

means I want to set the local variable of structure which will be the input value increased by one?

Comment: Yes, the data member of your newly-constructed struct will be equal to the argument value + 1. Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: @Dúthomhas I not much experienced in C++ and I tryed to explain what I expect that construction do. The expected behaviour is take the input and set local variable to input + 1. But I was not sure about it, beacause lack of knowledge of C++ language. So you probably understand it well.

Comment: I suggest you read up on [Classes in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/). That should clarify the difference between the declaration and definition. I don't know if there is this separation in Java.

Comment: @RawN Thanks there is explained this shortcut using member initialization, which makes the code in my opinion really unreadable. In java there are used terms like definition and declaration. Java also don't have structs, but the classes is kind of equivalent for that. But both the definition and declaration of class in Java is on one place not like in C or C++, which makes the code also more readable.

Comment: @RawN: in Java, all functionality is defined inline, so there is no separate declaration.

Comment: FWIW, what you call "local variables" are usually called "data members" or "instance variables". "Local variables" are variables local to a **function**, not members of a struct.